# how do i append this file and what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

Ok, so im trying to append a file but i cant see any visual errors and the screen doesnt give me errors, yet for some reason the file doesnt append. what do i do? Im a beginning python programmer. here is my code:

```
b = open("games.txt", "r")
c = open("games1.txt", "w")
avar = b.readline()
while avar != "ZZZZ                 -9999       zzzz       ZZZZ          ZZZZ   ":
    c.write(avar)
    avar = b.readline()
c.close()
b.close()


d = open("games1.txt", "r")
text = d.read()
print(text)
d.close()


e = open("games1.txt", "a")
newField = ""
newField = input("Enter the field’s data: ")
e.write(newField + "\n")
e.close


f = open("games1.txt", "r")
texto = f.read()
print(texto)
f.close()


print()
print()
print("-" * 50)
print("Name:  NuAmen, Period 1, Roster 01")
print("p1 r01 audena nuamen exer 003.py")

blah = input("Press ENTER to quit.")
```

When run it reads this:

```
Super smash bros 4    2014       F          Both          Nintendo
Splatoon 2            2017       Sh         both          Nintendo
Monopoly              1935       M          Offline       Parker Brothers
Super mario oddysey   2017       P          Offline       Nintendo
Clash Royale          2016       S          Online        Supercell
Call of duty          2003       sh/act     online        Activision
Enter the field’s data:
```

I enter something:

```
Super smash bros 4    2014       F          Both          Nintendo
Splatoon 2            2017       Sh         both          Nintendo
Monopoly              1935       M          Offline       Parker Brothers
Super mario oddysey   2017       P          Offline       Nintendo
Clash Royale          2016       S          Online        Supercell
Call of duty          2003       sh/act     online        Activision

Enter the field’s data: Grand theft auto      1997       act        offline       DMA Design
```

And i want it to print this:

```
Super smash bros 4    2014       F          Both          Nintendo
Splatoon 2            2017       Sh         both          Nintendo
Monopoly              1935       M          Offline       Parker Brothers
Super mario oddysey   2017       P          Offline       Nintendo
Clash Royale          2016       S          Online        Supercell
Call of duty          2003       sh/act     online        Activision
Grand theft auto      1997       act        offline       DMA Design
```

But instead it prints this:

```
Super smash bros 4    2014       F          Both          Nintendo
Splatoon 2            2017       Sh         both          Nintendo
Monopoly              1935       M          Offline       Parker Brothers
Super mario oddysey   2017       P          Offline       Nintendo
Clash Royale          2016       S          Online        Supercell
Call of duty          2003       sh/act     online        Activision
```

What do i do?

Comment: You're missing parentheses after when closing `e`. Try adding them and see if it's maybe not flushing since you're not closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put **()** on the close() method. It is a syntax error.
Though I don't understand what this para here does.

```
print()
print()
print("-" * 50)
print("Name:  NuAmen, Period 1, Roster 01")
print("p1 r01 audena nuamen exer 003.py")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that paragraph is required for mu programming class. its nothing really important.